# React MSW - my code does not mock and actual API gets called

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, msw

I am trying to test the below component `App.js`. The component is a simple one that sends a GET request using fetch and displays the result.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAllUsers = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setUsers(data);
      } catch (err) {
        setError("Something went wrong!");
      }
    };
    fetchAllUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>List of Users</h1>
      {error && <div>{error}</div>}
      {users ? (
        <ul>
          {users.map((user) => (
            <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      ) : (
        <p>No users found</p>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The below is my `App.test.js`. I did this with the help of tutorials.

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { rest } from "msw";
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";
import App from "./App";

const server = setupServer(
  rest.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", (req, res, ctx) => {
    res(ctx.json(["Hello World"]));
  })
);

beforeAll(() => {
  server.listen();
});

afterAll(() => {
  server.close();
});

test("empty", async () => {
  render(<App />);
  expect(screen.getByText("List of Users")).toBeInTheDocument();
  await screen.findByText("Hello world");
});
```

My test case fails with the below details.

```
Unable to find an element with the text: Hello world. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<body>
  <div>
    <h1>
      List of Users
    </h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Leanne Graham
      </li>
      /*skipping a few lines of HTML*/          
      <li>
        Clementina DuBuque
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

I can see that mocking hasn't happened and the original API is called. Please help me find my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return the `res(ctx.json(['Hello World']));`. Otherwise, msw will  throw an warning:

> [MSW] Expected a mocking resolver function to return a mocked response Object, but got: undefined. Original response is going to be used instead.

e.g.

`App.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAllUsers = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
                const data = await response.json();
                setUsers(data);
            } catch (err) {
                setError('Something went wrong!');
            }
        };
        fetchAllUsers();
    }, []);

    console.log(users);

    return (
        <>
            <h1>List of Users</h1>
            {error && <div>{error}</div>}
            {users ? <div>{users[0]}</div> : <p>No users found</p>}
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

`App.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { rest } from 'msw';
import { setupServer } from 'msw/node';
import App from './App';
import React from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

const server = setupServer(
    rest.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', (req, res, ctx) => {
        return res(ctx.json(['Hello World']));
    }),
);

beforeAll(() => {
    server.listen();
});

afterAll(() => {
    server.close();
});

test('empty', async () => {
    render(<App />);
    expect(screen.getByText('List of Users')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(await screen.findByText('Hello World')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    'jest-extended',
    './jest.setup.js'
  ],
};
```

`jest.setup.js`:

```js
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/76998600/App.test.tsx (6.264 s)
  ✓ empty (48 ms)

  console.log
    null

      at App (stackoverflow/76998600/App.tsx:20:10)

  console.log
    [ 'Hello World' ]

      at App (stackoverflow/76998600/App.tsx:20:10)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   93.75 |       75 |     100 |   93.33 |                   
 App.tsx  |   93.75 |       75 |     100 |   93.33 | 14                
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.492 s
```

package version:

```json
"msw": "^0.29.0",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
```